# How to avoid full Streamlit app re-run on user input?

Tags: streamlit

I have a very large streamlit app (lots of code, data processing, etc... slow even after caching almost everything). Towards the bottom of the page there is a user input, and some content is rendered depending on the input. Here is some illustrative code:

```py
import streamlit as st
st.title('Hello App')

# Lots of code, inputs, charts, functions, images, etc...
# Pretty much everything is cached, but even then 
# just displaying it on the screen still takes 1-5 seconds

animal = st.selectbox('What do you want to learn more about?', ['Dogs', 'Cats', 'Fish', ...])

st.write(f'Ok, let me tell you about {animal}')
```

In the app as shown, all the charts, images, etc... are re-rendered / re-run whenever the user changes the "animal".

Is there a way to avoid this?

Comment: There is no way to avoid this. See the main concept of streamlit - https://docs.streamlit.io/library/get-started/main-concepts#data-flow

Comment: I understand the intended flow - I mean, is there no setting, callback, plugin, or fork of streamlit that might help?